# I lost kibana data but other elasticsearch index data are fine

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Somehow I lost kibana data

- index patterns
- visualizations
- dashboards

are gone.

But I can see raw data (indices) in elasticsearch are there.

What would be the likely reason for the loss?

I'm using the official kibana docker (7.4.2)

I use the following setting. (I don't see any data related setting other than `ES` hosts setting and it's been fixed.

```
logging.dest: /var/log/kibana/kibana.log
server.host: "localhost"
elasticsearch.hosts: ["http://<ELASTICSEARCH_HOST>:<ELASTICSEARCH_PORT>"]
```

Another possibly related bug is that, I saw `too many redirects` after sometime kibana boots up (few days after boot-up)

```
wget http://localhost:5601/                                                                                                                                           112339ms
--2020-07-29 11:55:10--  http://localhost:5601/
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:5601... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /app/kibana [following]
--2020-07-29 11:55:10--  http://localhost:5601/app/kibana
Reusing existing connection to localhost:5601.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: / [following]
--2020-07-29 11:55:11--  http://localhost:5601/
Reusing existing connection to localhost:5601.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /app/kibana [following]
--2020-07-29 11:55:11--  http://localhost:5601/app/kibana
Reusing existing connection to localhost:5601.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: / [following]
--2020-07-29 11:55:11--  http://localhost:5601/
Reusing existing connection to localhost:5601.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
```

and I had to restart docker container, but restarting shouldn't delete `.kibana` data does it? :(

Comment: Could this be the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63067062/4604579 ?

Comment: yeah, it seems very likely..