# secure Elasticsearch without SSL

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to secure elasticsearch without SSL
reason being, it's just too much work to maintain certificates ..

Is there a way to secure ES by setting up `userid/password` as we could for example with redis?

I see bunch of `meos` index and I think some bots are deleting our `.kibana` index from time to time.

Comment: This thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63067062/4604579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you've been meowed. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63067062/4604579) for more detailed information.

As soon as you turn on XPack security, you have to [configure TLS/SSL for internode-communication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/configuring-tls.html), that's a **requirement**. So it is not possible to just have basic authentication turned on and no SSL between the nodes UNLESS you have a single node. But since you're worried about too much work to maintain certificates, I assume you have several nodes, otherwise it wouldn't be an issue.

An alternative if you just want BASIC auth is to use the free version of the [Readonly REST plugin](https://readonlyrest.com/free/).