# (ELK) How to expose index name within Chrome Browser Developer Tools

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elk

Previously I had worked with a client who was using Elasticsearch to perform queries in there application.

I was able to see the index that was being queried from the chrome browser's developer tools.

I would just select the Network tab and click on search?q='string' after making a query from the application.

Now, I am making a standalone application, but when I click on search?q='string' it is not exposing the index name. I was wondering if there is something I have to do in the code or a setting I have to change to expose the index name in the browser during a query.

Comment: Just know that it's a very bad practice to access ES directly from your front-end application since you're exposing security credentials, provided your ELK cluster is [properly secured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067062/elastic-search-indexes-gets-deleted-frequently), and if not, it's even worse as anyone could gain access to your cluster and mess with your data.

Comment: Agreed. This was just in a Dev Environment, and I was able to get the issue resolved. Turns out I just had to delete all types in my indexes, since it's deprecated.