# Elasticsearch keeps loosing indices

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I have simple Elasticsearch database together with Kibana in Docker containers. The issue is that despite container keeps running, I repeatedly loose all my indices and thus all the data. I am forced to reinsert all of it, but after a day it is again gone. I have tried both single and multinode clusters, increasing memory limits, upgrading images etc. How to prevent this? Here is my current docker-compose file:

```yml
version: '2.2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:7.10.0
    depends_on:
      - es01
      - es02
      - es03
    links:
      - "es01:elasticsearch"
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    networks:
      - elastic
  es01:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    container_name: es01
    environment:
      - node.name=es01
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es02,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data01:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - 9200:9200
    networks:
      - elastic
 es02:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    container_name: es02
    environment:
      - node.name=es02
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es03
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data02:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic
 es03:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.10.0
    container_name: es03
    environment:
      - node.name=es03
      - cluster.name=es-docker-cluster
      - discovery.seed_hosts=es01,es02
      - cluster.initial_master_nodes=es01,es02,es03
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    volumes:
      - data03:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    networks:
      - elastic

volumes:
  data01:
    driver: local
  data02:
    driver: local
  data03:
    driver: local

networks:
  elastic:
    driver: bridge
```

In logs I have found something like this:

```
fatal error in thread [main], exiting
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:637)
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:289)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:227)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:227)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:393)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:161)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:127)
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:126)
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:92)
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "getClassLoader")
        at java.base/java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:1036)
        at java.base/java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:408)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.checkClassLoaderPermission(ClassLoader.java:2068)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.getParent(ClassLoader.java:1815)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:114)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:70)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:57)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:148)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:45)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:194)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:581)
        at org.elasticsearch.persistent.PersistentTasksService.<clinit>(PersistentTasksService.java:49)
        ... 12 more
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-11-20T02:13:00,006Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction", "cluster.name": "es-docker-cluster", "node.name": "es01", "message": "Deleting expired data", "cluster.uuid": "B76EHJrlTzG80_NuQFjCqQ", "node.id": "oCU5GS2xStSf4q7IPtdcTA"  }
```

Comment: Did you check the Elasticsearch logs??, also see if its related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63067062/elastic-search-indexes-gets-deleted-frequently and you also have similar logs?

Comment: I have updated original post with logs, but I do not know if this is related

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with policies, it turn out that I was targeted by a malicious bot - it left a read_me file with ransom demand. API was publicly accessible and thus it was an easy target.

Answer (score 1):

If you notice below message, its looks like some policy is defined in your cluster which is deleting the expired data(what is this expiry you need to figure out).

> {"type": "server", "timestamp": "2020-11-20T02:13:00,006Z", "level":
> "INFO", "component": "o.e.x.m.a.TransportDeleteExpiredDataAction",
> "cluster.name": "es-docker-cluster", "node.name": "es01", "message":
> "Deleting expired data", "cluster.uuid": "B76EHJrlTzG80_NuQFjCqQ",
> "node.id": "oCU5GS2xStSf4q7IPtdcTA"  }

But check if you [ILM](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-lifecycle-management.html) which is deleting the indices.